# International address State/Country data

Tags: states, raw-data

I am trying to create a dropdown that automatically will provide a set of states based on a country, so you will have:

```
(United States)  -> filled with (Us States)
(Canada)         -> filled with (Provinces)
(etc.)
```

I need these to be the proper mailing address states.  Does anyone know where I can get some JSON of this?  Actually I dont mind any format, I just need some raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has what you want:

http://www.commondatahub.com/live/geography/state_province_region/fips_states_codes